# When is lit-element properties `hasChanged` called?

Tags: javascript, properties, lit-element

I have a simple lit-element with a property that has a `hasChanged` function.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
</head>
<body>

<script type="module">
  import {LitElement, html} from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/lit-element@0.7.0/lit-element.js?module';

  class MyElement extends LitElement {

    static get properties() {
      return {
        mood: {
          type: String,
          hasChanged: function(value, oldValue) {
            console.log(oldValue, " -> ", value);
            return BOOLEAN; // <== replace with true or false
          }
        }
      };
    }

    constructor() {
      super();
      this.mood = 'default';
    }

    render() {
      return html`${this.mood}`;
    }

  }

  customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
</script>

<my-element mood="explicit"></my-element>

</body>
</html>
```

For the displayed result it doesn't matter whether you replace `BOOLEAN` by `true` or `false`. Both display `explicit`.

But the log outputs are different:

- with `true` you get only one line:

```
undefined  ->  default
```

- with `false` you get two lines:

```
undefined  ->  default
default  ->  explicit
```

The '`false`' log output is what I expected. With lit-element until 0.6.5 you get the the same two lines also by returning `true`.

Is this a Bug introduced in lit-element 0.7.0 or is the new behavior valid? And if it is valid, why is no second call done by returning `true` from the first call.

Comment: It's not a bug as described in [Issue 449](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/issues/449).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was as a performance optimization and always set the value set as attribute without call this function.

After the component is updated first time, this function is called whenever the property is set. You can compare the property’s old and new values, and evaluates whether or not the property has changed.

This function decide if an update will occur (returns true) or not (returns false)

More info: https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties#configure-property-changes

Comment: I have created a [bug report](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/issues/449).

Comment: It is not is called *whenever* the property is set, as the answer in the bug report pointed out. The documentation is wrong in this point. Can you please adjust your answer to the one in the bug report? I'll accept it then.